# gstreamer OpenCV stream MPEG from live still images

Tags: opencv, camera, usb, gstreamer

In a Raspberry pi3, I've got a c program that grabs raw images 8bits YUY from an USB CAM (FLIR Boson) with the V4l2 driver.

These files are buffered in memory and displayed with imshow( , ) openCV function and refresh at a framerate of 9FPS with good quality and latency. 
Do you think it's possible with gstreamer to use these images Inside the c program and stream them as a MPEG streaming? Not sure that multifilesrc can refresh in live with the new image.

Others methods like gst-launch-1.0 or ffmpeg to capture directly from the v4l2 devices worked but with a very bad quality and a not acceptable latency.

Thank you very much
Rgds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you already have the c code to get the raw image data, you can [use appsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html#inserting-data-with-appsrc) or write [your own GStreamer source element](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/element-types/base-classes.html#writing-a-source).

Possibly also [v4l2src](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-v4l2src.html) can be improved for your use case?  Did you put a [queue](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-queue.html) element in your pipeline after v4lsrc?

Why do you want to use multifilesrc?  Consider using an RTP stream over udp or tcp.

Comment: Thank you very much @micha137 for your answer. appsrc will be definitively the best solution to stream Mat raw object to udp with gstreamer element. Inserting !queue! and mostly tune=zerolatancy to the x264enc encoder solved almost all the issues of quality and latancy. thks, rgds